# ATG Cache cull vs invalidate

Tags: caching, atg, oracle-commerce

Can anyone provide definitions for `entryInvalidations` vs `localItemCulls` in respect to ATG Repository cache usage statistics?  The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24152_01/Platform.10-1/ATGRepositoryGuide/html/s1012monitoringcacheusage01.html) for caches does not appear to have been updated with an explanation on what these items are.

These can be viewed through dyn/admin on any of ootb repositories in the cache usage statistics section e.g. `atg/userprofiling/ProfileAdapterRepository/`

I suspect this relates to entries which have expired due to a cache timeout vs entries which have been removed as a result of a high cache churn rate.

Please note this question is NOT about local vs external caches.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a breakdown of what those things are:

`localCulls` - The number of times items were displaced out of the item cache as a result of new items being loaded, but the cache was full.

`localItemsCulled` - The number of items that were culled out of the cache as a result of a local cull (see above).

`localMaxCulled` - The maximum number of items that were pushed out of the cache at once

`weakCulls` - The number of times the weak item cache is cleared. This will increase by 1 when you manually invoke the clearWeakTables() method on the repository via the component browser.

`weakItemsCulled` - The number of items that were culled out of the weak item cache. This will occur when the weak item cache is cleared and this number is the count of how many items have been GCed and therefore removed from the weak item cache.

`weakMaxCulled` - Like `localMaxCulled`, it is the maximum number of weak item entries that were cleared at once.